# Как увидеть все переменные, которые задействованы в Microsoft Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++

Мне выпала производственная необходимость вносить изменения в код, который был разработан в Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Уважаемые коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такая опция в MVS2008 как увидеть все переменные, которые использованы в методе одним списком?

Суть в том, что предшественник накодил методы в 100 строк и более, и даже половину переменных держать в голове как-то не очень получается.

Comment: Может быть, имеет смысл зарефакторить длинные методы, деля их на более короткие, пока код не станет обозримым? Заодно и качество кода улучшится.

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать скопировать проект и открыть его более свежей версией студии, если в ней возможности получше.

Comment: @VladD идеи хорошие, только более лучшей версией IDE всё вылетает. или работает не так.

Comment: Ну, я не имел в виду использовать новую IDE для _разработки_. А лишь для того, чтобы посмотреть список переменных в удобной форме, и вернуться в старую IDE.

Comment: если вылетает в новой студии, точно надо рефакторинг делать, значит код не соответствует стандартам или  приводил к неопределенному поведению (2008-2010 не соответствовали никаким стандартам кроме самих мелкомягких) для 2010 -2012 есть куча плагинов да и компилятор без явных ошибок трансляции

Comment: @Swift спасибо.